# Select first result only... is there a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There can be multiple Config_RecID's, but I only want to show the first one attached to the SR_Service_RecID, or NULL when null.

```
SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID
     , sc.Config_RecID

  FROM SR_Service s
       LEFT JOIN SR_Config sc
              ON sc.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID

 WHERE (sc.Config_RecID = 
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 sc.Config_RecID
             FROM SR_Config sc 
            WHERE sc.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
       ) 
       OR sc.Config_RecID IS NULL)
```

Is there a better/neater way to do this, or am I on the right track?

Comment: Sorry, but neither `sql` nor `tsql` in the tags implies a specific SQL product, not to mention a specific version thereof. Please be specific about what you are using, maybe there *is* an efficient alternative in your particular case.

Comment: Good point. Added in sql-server.

Comment: All right. And which version, please? It matters whether it's 2005+ or not.

Comment: Added in 2008. It's actually 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the condition into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT s.SR_Service_RecID
     , sc.Config_RecID
FROM SR_Service s
LEFT JOIN SR_Config sc
     ON sc.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
     AND sc.Config_RecID = (
           SELECT TOP 1 Config_RecID
           FROM SR_Config sc2 
           WHERE sc2.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
     )
```

That way you don't need the extra check for `sc.Config_RecID IS NULL`

Comment: Definitely a better way of doing it, thanks. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Config_RecIDs as (
   select SR_Service_RecID
      , Config_RecID
      , row_number() over (partition by SR_Service_RecID order by Config_RecID) as [rn]
   from SR_Config
)
select sc.SR_Service_RecID, c.Config_RecID
from SR_Config as sc
left join Config_RecIDs as s
   on s.SR_Service_RecID = c.SR_Service_RecID
   and [rn] = 1
```

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't put `rn = 1` into WHERE, that'll make your outer join an inner join. Instead, add it via AND to the ON clause. Or, if you do mean an inner join, just replace LEFT with INNER to avoid confusion.

Comment: Whoops! The where clause should have been a join condition; code edited.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
;WITH SR_ConfigCTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         SR_Service_RecID
        ,Config_RecID
    FROM SR_Config
)
SELECT   s.SR_Service_RecID
        ,sc.Config_RecID
FROM SR_Service     s
LEFT 
JOIN SR_ConfigCTE   sc ON sc.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
```

Comment: For some reason still showing all results, not just the first one, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TOP N, you're on the wrong track.  It's nonstandard and nondeterministic.

Instead, you want the first ... something.  Find it with `min()`.  Join to that or use a correlated subquery.

I don't really understand your query, but here's a simpler one that gives the first name for every type:

```
select type, usertype, cast(name as varchar(30)) as name 
from systypes as t
where exists 
      ( select 1 from systypes 
        group by type 
        having min(name) = t.name 
        and type = t.type 
) 
order by type
```

This yields:

```
 type usertype name                          
 ---- -------- ------------------------------
    0        0 xml                           
   34       20 image                         
   35        0 ntext                         
   37        0 uniqueidentifier              
   39        0 nvarchar                      
   45        3 binary                        
   47        1 char                          
   48        5 tinyint                       
   50       16 bit                           
   52        6 smallint                      
   55       24 decimal                       
   56        7 int                           
   58       22 smalldatetime                 
   59       23 real                          
   60       11 money                         
   61       12 datetime                      
   62        8 float                         
   63        0 bigint                        
  122       21 smallmoney
```